# Camera find saved photo

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm using this [app](https://github.com/pinguo-yuyidong/Camera2), it's working fine when I take picture and it's saved in my phone gallery, but I can't find which part of the code is used to save the picture so I can use this image ( crop it ) before I sav it.

Can any body point the part of the code that is used to save the token photo ?

This is the [class](https://github.com/pinguo-yuyidong/Camera2/blob/master/camera2/src/main/java/us/yydcdut/camera2/ui/PreviewFragment.java) responsible for the save of the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ImageSaver`](https://github.com/pinguo-yuyidong/Camera2/blob/master/camera2/src/main/java/us/yydcdut/camera2/ImageSaver.java) and [`DngImageSaver`](https://github.com/pinguo-yuyidong/Camera2/blob/master/camera2/src/main/java/us/yydcdut/camera2/DngImageSaver.java) have image-saving code.

If the class has a keyword in its name (e.g., "save") that interests you, the class may have the code that interests you.

Comment: I thought the same why and I did search for the world save and relate to same methods but i can't find the variable that hold the image ( bitmap byte[] .. ) ?

Comment: @Svg_af: You can easily search those Web pages for occurrences of `byte[]` using your favorite Web browser. For example, one occurrence of `byte[]` appears in [this method](https://github.com/pinguo-yuyidong/Camera2/blob/master/camera2/src/main/java/us/yydcdut/camera2/ImageSaver.java#L92-L107).